# Does firebase set apns-push-type header automatically?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

According to [changes in iOS 13](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/sending_notification_requests_to_apns) for APNS, silent push notifications require additional header (`apns-push-type`).

I use Firebase as a mediator between backend and mobile, and I'm wondering if Firebase sets mentioned header automatically when `content-available` property is set to true.

It is already happening in AWS, as mentioned [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-send-custom-platform-specific-payloads-mobile-devices.html).

Can I check somehow in iOS if this header was passed to silent push notification?

I've tested on my devices and everything is working after I updated Firebase dependency to the newest version, even in background. But still I don't have any proof how the header looks like.

Comment: Hi @Nominalista, currently fireabase does not provide any documentation regarding iOS 13 update. You can connect their support, I guess they add this header you can check in iOS 13. I will check on my end and update you.

Comment: Thanks, please let me know, when you will find out something.

Answer (score 6):

After digging around a little bit and checking how some open source projects updated their code, here's an example on how to add `apns-push-type` to Firebase Admin Node:

(I'm using multicast, so your solution might differ.)

```
const message = {
  priority: 'high',
  sound: 'default',
  notification: {
    title: 'Message Title',
    body: 'Message Body',
  },
  android: { ... },
  apns: {
    headers: {  // Add these 3 lines
      'apns-push-type': 'alert',
    },
    payload: {
      aps: {
        badge: 1,
        sound: 'default',
      },
    },
  },
  tokens: [ ... ],
};

admin.messaging().sendMulticast(message);
```

I only had a few notifications failing so I haven't been able to fully confirm that the problem is solved yet.

Answer (score 4):

This is what i'm using to send background notificaions to the ios devices. Notice that im setting "contentAvailable" instead of "content-available", everything needs to be a string.

```
"apns": {
    "headers": {
      "apns-push-type": "background",
      "apns-priority": "5"
    },
    "payload": {
      "aps":{
        "contentAvailable": true
      }
    }
  }
```

i'm using sendMulticast() method,
full example looks something like this:

```
var message = {
  "tokens": tokensArray,
  "data": {
    "info":"someInfo"
  },
  "apns": {
    "headers": {
      "apns-push-type": "background",
      "apns-priority": "5"
    },
    "payload": {
      "aps":{
        "contentAvailable": true
      }
    }
  }
};

await messaging.sendMulticast(message)
```

Answer (score 2):

Firebase support responded on my request.

As of today, Firebase does not automatically set the `apns-push-type` header if `content_available` is set. One should set it via the header in [ApnsConfig](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.messaging.ApnsConfig).
They also recommend to update to the lastest admin SDK version.

I additionally set the `apns-priority`header. Unfortunately all steps didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Have you tried using underscore? Like `apns_push_type`? Notice that for Apple accepts `content-available` property and Firebase accepts `content_available` in contrast.